# Gatsbyjs + Netlify CMS how to create a new page and use javascript functions on the new page

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I need to create a new page or just re-use the existing About page
to add one html textbox which will call a subscribe(event) function when users click Enter.

[image]

As you can see here, I'm using Netlify CMS's admin portal to modify my About page. I did pay attention to the empty lines in-between `<input>` and `<script>` as someone said to have a few empty line in the middle to make them work.

The issue is it works sometime, but when I update anything on the page, the code breaks saying the function "subscribe(e)" is not defined even I have the script there.

Comment: Don't forget that if you use HTML or XML elements in a Stack Overflow post, you have to backtick them. `<input>` and `<script>` were missing here (amusingly enough, in the section about paying attention!).

Comment: @halfer SOF and NetlifyCMS are using different markdown formatter. I did try the backtick, it just converted the html code into string.

Comment: No, you are missing what I am saying. On Stack Overflow, if you don't use `inline formatting` on HTML elements, they disappear, and the question then makes no sense at all. It is essential to read the preview window to ensure your question says what you believe you have written.

Comment: okie, @halfer you were talking about the ```<input>``` and ```<script>``` . Got it, thanks